# Distinct values in Microsoft Graph query

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I would like to list out all our departmentnames fra Microsoft Graph (graph.microsoft.com). I guess that the only way to do this is throught the list of users, please correct me if I am wrong.

So my question is, is there any way to query users for Departments and only distinct values of Departments?

```
This code does not work, but just to you an idea of where I want: 

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$Select=Department&$Distinct(Department)
```

Comment: You have to use the [filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/query-parameters#filter-parameter) parameter as `Distinct` is not supported in `Microsoft graph API` additionally, You need to loop through users to fetch each departmentName.

Comment: Thanks, guess I was hoping for a miracle (beta versions etc.)
Our user directory is 30k+, so I was not to eager to download them all.

Comment: Then `filter` might help you. Feel free to let me know if you need any more assistance.