# MS Graph get all values of a field

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api

In my app, the user should be able to choose a company, in which his article gets published.
The Azure Active Directory has the Company name for that, which is maintained by our AAD Team. Is there any way to request all values from this field? Like a SELECT DISTINCT in SQL?

Comment: `"Is there any way to request all values from this field?"` Which value do you mean? Its not clear by `all value` what exactly you are refering to?

Comment: Is the question related to SharePoint? Which Graph API endpoint do you call?

Comment: @user2250152 no it's not SP-related. I want all distinct values of the attribute companyName

Answer (score 0):

**AFAIK**, currently there is no way to request all distinct values using **`companyName`** attribute.

You can use [**filter**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/query-parameters#filter-parameter) parameter by looping through each `companyName`.

> **Please note that Distinct is not supported in Microsoft graph API.**

***You can raise Azure Support ticket or feature request for the same by visiting below link:***

[Azure Support Options | Microsoft Azure](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/support/options/)

**References:**

[Is there a way to query distinct user profile attribute values from the Graph API? For example $select=Distinct(jobTitle)? The scenario would be to build a "refinement" experience for a People Search experience. - Microsoft Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/280487/is-there-a-way-to-query-distinct-user-profile-attr.html)

[Distinct values in Microsoft Graph query - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60921377/distinct-values-in-microsoft-graph-query)